# React Router this.props.location is always Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to set a class name to the name of the current path, for example, "inventory" or "about". However, when I try to use this.props.location it is always undefined. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

```
class Header extends Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <Router>
          <div className={'header ' + this.props.location}>
            <div className="header-content">        
                <div className="header-right">
                <NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/inventory">Inventory</NavLink>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="page-content">

            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/inventory" component={Inventory}/>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this component? Props need to be set somewhere by something, they're not magically there.

Comment: @F.P I'm calling <Header/> in the return of my App component

Comment: Then you don't have any props because you're not setting them. Use `useLocation()` hook or the `withLocation()` HOC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router-dom: getting props.location from within <BrowserRouter> component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298325/react-router-dom-getting-props-location-from-within-browserrouter-component)

Answer (score 0):

the thing here is that `history`, `location` and blah blah blah are been inyected to the components that are in a `<Route />` but u are trying to access it from the same component were the router is been created. so or you created the router in a parent file of the current or instead use the window object

```
 <div className={'header ' + window.location}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move your router higher in the hierarchy, ideally to the component that renders your App component like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <App />
</Router>
```

You are currently trying to read location from props, but because you render Router in the same component, it can't pass the location to props and thus it will be always empty.
If you wrap your App by the Router, you can then pass the location props down to any other component where it is needed (for example Header).